# Evil-surround: How can I make `ves(` act like `ves)`?

Tags: evil

Same question for surrounding with bracket and braces as well. I'd like visually highlighted text to be surrounded without any added whitespace.

Currently `ves(` on `text` will result in `( text )` whereas `ves)` will result in `(text)`. Because I will never need the spaces I'd just like to make `ves({[` act like their closing parens/bracket/braces counterpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the variable `evil-surround-pairs-alist`, which (for me) holds the following:

```
((40 "( " . " )")
 (91 "[ " . " ]")
 (123 "{ " . " }")
 (41 "(" . ")")
 (93 "[" . "]")
 (125 "{" . "}")
 (35 "#{" . "}")
 (98 "(" . ")")
 (66 "{" . "}")
 (62 "<" . ">")
 (116 . evil-surround-read-tag)
 (60 . evil-surround-read-tag)
 (102 . evil-surround-function))
```

If you change `(40 "( " . " )")` to `(40 "(" . ")")`, the parentheses are inserted without spaces. This can also be done using `M-x customize`.